# Error: Couldn't find preset "es2015" relative to directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am writing a project and I have written another project that I am requiring in as a node module

I have npm linked the modules together and I import the npm module like so:

`const rh = require('richs-helpers');`

I get the error in the title in projectA when I run `npm run watch`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import rh from 'richs-helpers';

export default class QuizApp extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div></div>
  }
}
```

my .babelrc looks like so:

```
{
  "sourceMaps": true,
  "ignore": "/node_modules",
  "presets": ["es2015", "react", "stage-2"]
}
```

it's a simple react app just requiring my node module so  i cant understand the error

i have also tried requiring my module in instead of importing

also:

How can I remove this error?

Answer (score 0):

Did you install es2015 with "npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2015" ?
You can also try to delete "node_modules/" folder and run "npm install" again (if a problem occured while installing)
Have a look here : http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-es2015/

Comment: Then, try to run it with babel-node : https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/#babel-node